# Reading special column while avoiding some special characters in text file in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Can somebody help me about this please? : 
I have a text file in this form:

```
"1.101511000000E+02","-3.066300000000E+01"
"8.328840000000E+01","-7.020080000000E+01"
"1.053746000000E+02","-4.622800000000E+01"
"1.314320000000E+01","-7.866200000000E+01"
"9.876160000000E+01","-5.844720000000E+01"
"3.129990000000E+01","-7.919930000000E+01"
"7.152530000000E+01","-7.527770000000E+01"
"2.849310000000E+01","-7.933210000000E+01"
"7.602290000000E+01","-7.410480000000E+01"`
```

it has 4003 lines. I want to read these columns like avoiding the characters: '"' and ','.
Then I read the signs + or - and recognize the 'E' to make the power and write my results to another file and then use it later. I give you an example of what I need:
1.101511000000   +02    -3.066300000000   +01
And then what I have to do is for example once I get the first column :
1.101511000000 
and when I know that it's power 2 I do this:
1.101511000000 x 10² 
and what I will write to my new file is:

110.1511     -30.663
83.2884      -70.2
105.3746     -46.228

etc.

So the main questions are:
1) How can I read this text file and avoiding these special characters? 
2)finding the power written in form e.g E+02?
3)Doing the calculations?
4) avoiding all redundant 000 in float?
5) putting the results at the same time in a new file?

I appreciate you all in advance, but please consider that fact which this is very urgent and important for me now.

Mojdeh

Comment: Read the file line by line, use `fgets` or `getdelim`, use `strtok` to parse the line you read. Now Write your code,if you still have problems, show us what you tried.

Comment: It is a CSV file, Comma Separated Values.  Very common, you'll drown in the google hits for it.  Once you get the column strings then it is just strtod() or sscanf() to convert to double.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fscanf` to read the two numbers with their respective exponents.
Something like this:

```
fscanf(pFile, "\"%f\", \"%f\"", &number1, &number2);
```

Then all you have to do is write it back to the second file using `fprintf`, like this:

```
fprintf(pFile2, "%g %g", number1, number2);
```

The `%g` format prints the number using the shortest representation.

For more information on these functions go to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/.